# Integration of composed function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My question is related to a mechanics exercise but the aspect of the exercise where I'm struggling is related with calculus.

$a(t)=-kv^{-2}$ and $v$ is a function of $t$: $v(t)$.
When $t=0$, $v=v_0$ and $a(t)=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}$

The question is: Define $v(t)$.

Can anybody help me?
Cumps, João Couto.

Answer (score 0):

$$
a = -\dfrac{k}{v^2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \dfrac{dv}{dt} =-\dfrac{k}{v^2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \int_{v_0}^{v} u^2du = -\int_{0}^{t}kd\tau \quad \Rightarrow
$$
$$
\dfrac{v^3}{3} - \dfrac{v_{0}^{3}}{3} = -kt \quad \Rightarrow \quad v(t) = \sqrt[3]{v_{0}^3 - 3kt}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes perfect sense!